# IPv6 List address in postgres

Tags: postgresql, ipv6

For IPv4 in Postgres I do the following.

```
    SELECT set_masklen(((generate_series(1,
(2 ^ (32 - masklen('10.10.100.0/24'::cidr)))::integer - 2) +
'10.10.100.0/24'::cidr)::inet), 32) as ip
```

This will list all of the ips from 1 to 254. My question is how can I do this with IPv6 as well ??

Comment: With IPv6, there are 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 host addresses per subnet. Why would you ever want to list each of them? Do you realize how long that would take?

Comment: [The cidr and inet types support IPv6](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-net-types.html), so the basic technique should still work.  However, RonMaupin has pointed out the absurdity of the technique with IPv6, so you may with to rethink your premise.  Maybe explain what problem you're solving by listing every subnet host?

Comment: It will only display subnet so max address it will have is 255.

Comment: @NoName2, An IPv6 network is 64 bits, and the interface (host) address is 64 bits. Using a mask length longer than 64 is not allowed, except for point-to-point links (/126 or /127) or loopback addresses (/128). Assuming 1 ms per address to generate and save the address, you are looking at over 584,942,417 years (!) to complete the task. Many things in IPv6 are different, should not, or cannot be handled the same way as have been in IPv4.

Comment: Ok, but is there anyway of picking lets say last 10 address in a IPv6 subnet an then displaying them. I am clueless when it comes to IPv6. Or If these address are allocated then show them ?

Comment: @NoName2, it would help us to help you if you give us what you are trying to accomplish, and why. The subnet is 64 bits long, the first address would be the zero address (different than IPv4), the last address is all ones in each of the 64 bits.  For example,  for the network 2001:db8:1:2::/64, the first address is 2001:db8:1:2:: (or 2001:db8:1:2:0:0:0:0), and the last address is 2001:db8:1:2:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff. Each word between the colons is 16 bits (0 to 65535), represented as a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Also, how you assign the addresses (SLAAC, DHCPv6, static, etc.) and your OS will dictate which addresses are actually assigned. SLAAC will take the MAC (48 bits) address of the network interface, apply some magic, and create a 64 bit address based on the MAC address. Most OSes will assign several addresses and change them on a regular basis. Any of that may render moot what you want to do.